# Converting JSON String to Java Object with jersey

Tags: java, json, jersey

I am new to REST , JSON and Jersey usage. Now we got a requirement where we need to implement a Client which need need to query the server with JSON request, GET and going to receive a JSON String/Object, which need to be parsed and converted into local datastructure.

Could someone help me for the below points?

1. What I need to download for implementing REST Client application for supporting JSON ( we have restrictions to use Jersey apis, and no other third-party apis)
2. Sample java client code for requesting and parsing the JSON data.

Comment: The two most widely used libraries is `FasterXML` (my favorite) and Google's `GSON` library.

Comment: IF you are new in something the fastest approach is to start with some tutorial, that can be easily found in web.

Comment: Careful using the word REST. Representational State Transfer is a specific architecture that follows a handful of constraints--I believe the word you are looking for here is HTTP Client. Not being a nitpicker, head over to Roy Fielding's blog to see how serious he is about people misusing the word REST :)

Answer (score 1):

"What do I need ?", It really depends of the technology you want to use with it .. eg, if you use glassfish (netbeans server), you can use their jersey "org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.JacksonFeature" as json provider and the other ressources glassfish includes. You won't need anything else for a simple implementation.

As you are a beginner, you better follow a tutorial like this one : http://java.dzone.com/news/simple-restful-web-services

Comment: Thanks for the support. Currenlty I have implemented the

Comment: Client code with java net package options as : URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/services/");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");.. Now i need help for converting the JSON object or string output to java object

Comment: @user3683358 If you don't need any other help, please mark the best answer and 'up' the answers that helped you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert String to a JSONObject -

Use this library - http://www.json.org/java/

JAR file is available at http://code.google.com/p/org-json-java/downloads/list

Use below code to convert a string to JSONObject -

```
 JSONObject final_result = new JSONObject(result);
```